# Pandas .loc return some empty arrays so I can't get their values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I'm crossing the information into two tables. I want to get the information from the column `Register Number` in the table `profile` and put it into the column `Delivers`, which I just created, into the table `consumption`, by using the information into the columns `Cod. Deliver profile` and `Cod. agent profile` - which is the same for the same delivers. I do it by using the following code:

```
consumption['Delivers'] = ''
for idx, x in consumption['Cod. Deliver profile'].iteritems():
    consumption['Delivers'].iloc[idx] = profile.loc[profile['Cod. agent profile'] == x, 'Register Number'].values
```

The problem is that the method `.values` returns a `Numpy array`, which is not what I want - as below. It should have just one value of type string per cell and when there is no value to be set, empty or something else - but no brackets!

```
29                  []  
30                  []  
31   [6981180000116.0]   
42    [357038000116.0]  
43                  []  
44  [28152650000171.0]
```

If I use `.item()` I get the following error:
`ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar`

If I use `.iloc[0]` I get the following:
`IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

How to workaround this?

Comment: Can you share how both data frames look? One workaround would be to follow your code up by consumption['Delivers'] = consumption['Delivers'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if 0 < len(x) else None)

Comment: Why not use merge? What is your expected outcome go that new column.

Comment: @Rutger however I need the index to set the value in the correct column... that's why I use `iloc[idx}`.

Comment: @JonathanLeon the two dataframes have many columns and the values in the `Delivers` must be aligned to the correct rows in `Cod. Deliver profile`.

Comment: Still not clear, sorry. You want a column with multiple values in the cell but not a list? You want a string instead? This is where you're losing me.

Comment: @JonathanLeon sorry! Each cell must have only one value of type string. However, it seems that when the condition is not matched it returns an empty array - that's the problem.

Comment: So when the condition is not matched, instead of [], what you want to fill?

Comment: @Ank anything... it can be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by **Rutger** in comments, after you create your `consumption['Delivers']` column which contains arrays as values, you just need to use `apply` method to extract the values and convert them to string type, and `'0'` in case of an empty array:

```
consumption['Delivers'] = ''
for idx, x in consumption['Cod. Deliver profile'].iteritems():
    consumption['Delivers'].iloc[idx] = profile.loc[profile['Cod. agent profile'] == x, 'Register Number'].values

consumption['Delivers'] = consumption['Delivers'].apply(lambda x: str(x[0]) if len(x) > 0 else '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing the same thing, but not in two steps is:

```
consumption['Delivers'] = ''
for idx, x in consumption['Cod. Deliver profile'].iteritems():
     if len(profile.loc[profile['Cod. agent profile'] == x, 'Register Number'])>0:    
         consumption['Delivers'].iloc[idx] = profile.loc[profile['Cod. agent profile'] == x, 'Register Number'].values[0]
     else:
         0
```